# Get Meta Cost data via API in R

Tags: r, facebook

I tried to use [rfacebookstat](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/rfacebookstat/) package in R.

```
k1_listaKont <- fbGetAdAccounts(username = "seba@seo.pl", )
```

I used the function as mentioned [here](https://netpeak.net/blog/how-to-extract-marketing-campaign-statistics-from-facebook-api-using-r/), but this code gives me data from some test account (as below), not ad accounts available in my business manager.

[image]

How can I download data not from my personal account, but from my business manager, instead?